# how to obtain quiz id a user is currently playing in moodle

Tags: php, moodle

/*** In moodle  ******/

Like we obtain user id using **$USER->id** dynamically who is logged in  ,how can we obtain the quiz id of which the user is currently playing ? is there any option like **$QUIZ->id** or something else ?.Please help

Comment: Where is your code? We cant help you, with no code.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, if its been set up correctly, you can get the course module from the $PAGE object.

```
$cm = $PAGE->cm
```

Then grab the quiz record from the $cm object

```
$quiz = $DB->get_record('quiz', array('id' => $cm->instance));
```

Comment: Hi, referring to [this diagram](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Quiz_database_structure), does this return a `$quiz` object, i.e. a row in the `quiz` table?